# What the parameters before brackets mean?

Tags: pact-lang, kadena

In the documentation you can insert data inside a table with the following syntax:

`(insert table-name id {"parameter":parameterValue})`

But here, in this example i have extra values in parameters before the brackets.

`(insert loans-inventory (inventory-key loanId entityName) {"balance":loanAmount})`

What (inventorty-key loanId and entintynName) syntax mean? (inventory-key) is a function.

inventory-key function

```
(defun inventory-key (loanId:string owner:string)
(format "{}:{}" [loanId owner]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(inventory-key loanId entityName)` is a call to the `inventory-key` function with `loanId` and `entityName` as arguments. It all returns a value that serves the purpose as a key to the row that is being inserted in the table.

The key used comes from the output of the `inventory-key` function, which looking at the example (loans tutorial) it is a function that returns a string in the format of `loanId:owner`, probably to make it unique.